# iMacros: TAG Select doesn't work with Variable

Tags: imacros

Im using:
iMacros 8.9.6 for Firefox
Firefox 45.0
Mac OSX 10.10.5

The following is working:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/?RefID=A_a_763059 ATTR=ID:time CONTENT=%10:00
```

But this not

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/?RefID=A_a_763059 ATTR=ID:time CONTENT={{!COL7}}
```

i have checked {{!COL7}} with PROMPT *{{!COL7}}* and its %10:00

Any Ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/?RefID=A_a_763059 ATTR=ID:time CONTENT=${{!COL7}}
```